# Is gs_sh limited to show exact row data with SQL statements?

Tags: sql, database, time-series, griddb

I am manipulating data within GridDB, using its shell cliet `gs_sh`.
While I create and insert successfully, I found it not showing exact data with `select` cluase.
Seems nobody want to select within this tool, but what does `select` clause mean if it cannot show row data?

And, is it possible that I browse my data without any programing language?

reading and searching all over the official docs and google, discussing with GPT.

---

I tried these commands:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id INT,
  timestamp_column TIMESTAMP,
  other_column VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO table_name (id, timestamp_column, other_column)
VALUES (1, TO_TIMESTAMP_S(1686204096), 'Some data');
```

And when I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

I just get:

```
1 results. (13 ms)
```

rather than some exact data as other database do.

I want to know whether I can browse exact data with command lines.

Comment: Please tell us your data and the query so we can have a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: @Codelicious Hi, I've added some example code, thank you for your help

Comment: You have some type there, should be "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (1, TO_TIMESTAMP_MS(1686204096), 'Some data');". Also after getting the result you need to get the data by executing "get"

Comment: @Codelicious Hi, Thanks a lot! but how to execute "get" ? I didnt get any document about it.

Comment: Here is the manual: https://www.toshiba-sol.co.jp/en/pro/griddb/docs-en/v5_2/GridDB_OperationToolsReference.html#getting-search-results